# Is there a program that can change monitor color temperature for lighting?

Tags: software-recommendation, software, lighting, color

I'm shooting a scene for a film where the actor will be placed in front of a computer monitor. I want to use the monitor to light the actor, but I want to be able to adjust the color temperature to get the look I want. I have F.lux (https://justgetflux.com/), so I know changing monitor color temperature is possible, but I want to be able to control it. Preferably the program would be free, and I would be able to adjust the temperature in real time.

Comment: What do you want to show on the screen?

Comment: I was planning on using a white image fullscreen, and then being able to adjust the temperature from there.

Comment: You *can* use flux to set your monitor temperature manually ... also, what monitor are you using? Mostly all mordern monitors have in-built options to change color saturation, temperature, brightness ... or, even easier, couldn't you just use an orange/red/whatever-colored image in fullscreen mode?

Comment: I have an older AOC monitor, the settings on it aren't very in-depth. The main issue is I want to be able to adjust the temperature live so I can see what it looks like, which is why I want a program. I did look into f.lux settings a little more, and it allow some modification, but I'd like something a little more flexible if anyone knows of something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the other good answers. Here is what I ended up doing.

I created a blank white html page and made it fullscreen, and then used f.lux to adjust the color temperature. It worked for me, but I should point out to anyone looking to use this solution in the future that it isn't perfect. F.lux doesn't give a very broad range of color temperatures. They were enough for my purposes, but someone looking for a very warm or very cool look might not be satisfied. In addition, f.lux changes the color temperature for the entire desktop on all monitors, so if you have something color-sensitive running during the shoot, like using the computer as a monitor, your colors will be off on that as well.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a hack. You can use Blender and the [Blackbody Node](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/cycles/nodes/more.html?highlight=blackbody#blackbody) of *Cycles Render Engine*. Following example shows a **realtime viewport animation** of the color temperature in kelvin:

[image]

- Create some geometry (e.g. a plane) as **light emitter**
- Setup an **Emission shader**
- Create a **Blackbody node** and plug it into the **Emission Color**
- Position your camera
- Switch your Camera by pressing <kbd>Numpad 0</kbd>
- Set the **Viewport Shading to Rendered** or press <kbd>F12</kbd> to render the image

[image]

[**blend file**](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/35540)

---

#### Renderings

[image]

*2000K*

[image]

*4000K*

[image]

*6000K*

Comment: Ya, good idea.  If you can't adjust the monitor, then send it something other than pure white.  Blender seems like HUGE overkill.  I would have just booted Linux, logged in remotely, and done `DISPLAY=:0 xsetroot -solid '#fff'` to set a solid white background.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks Peter. You are right, OP was asking to control it by kelvins and I thought Cycles is physically accurate and have an instant viewport interactivity/rendering, so it could work :) Why not converting your comment into an answer? I would like to upvote it ;)

Comment: sure, why not? :P

Answer (score 2):

If you can't adjust the monitor, then send it something other than pure white.

@poor already posted an answer to do this with Blender, but that seems like HUGE overkill.  I would have just booted Linux, logged in remotely, and done `DISPLAY=:0 xsetroot -solid '#fff'` to set a solid white background, or any other color I wanted.

And there's probably something you could run to open a fullscreen window with a color of your choice, to save the trouble of switching to a window manager that didn't clutter up the screen borders with stuff.  Maybe a screensaver type of program?

I can't think off the top of my head what would give you a GUI color adjuster that would change most of the screen in realtime.

Comment: Using a seperate OS seems even more overkill than installing a freeware program tbh

Comment: You could additionally mention that it's possible to boot it via usb stick.

Comment: @Gin-San: If it was a computer I owned, it would already be running Linux :P  Obviously go with whatever OS you already use.